# Sass-mq. SassError: Function finished without @return

Tags: sass

I included sass-mq via npm and included the basic requirements with an responsive.scss partial.

```
$mq-breakpoints: (
    mobile:  320px,
    tablet:  740px,
    desktop: 980px,
    wide:    1300px
);

$mq-show-breakpoints: (mobile, mobileLandscape, tablet, desktop, wide); //todo: Disable on production build

@import 'mq';
```

Upon running the project I receive the error (Laravel-mix npm run watch)

```
ERROR in ./src/css/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Function finished without @return.
    ╷
125 │ ┌ @function mq-get-breakpoint-width($name, $breakpoints: $mq-breakpoints) {
126 │ │     @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $name) {
127 │ │         @return map-get($breakpoints, $name);
128 │ │     } @else {
129 │ │         @warn "Breakpoint #{$name} wasn't found in $breakpoints.";
130 │ │     }
131 │ └ }
  src/css/scss/utilities/_mq.scss 125:1        mq-get-breakpoint-width()
  src/css/scss/utilities/_mq.scss 350:21       mq-show-breakpoints()
  src/css/scss/utilities/_mq.scss 359:5        @import
  src/css/scss/utilities/responsive.scss 10:9  @import
  src/css/scss/utilities/_all.scss 3:9         @import
```

The error has an issue with @function. I know this is only a warn, but sass-mq isn't being pulled into the project whilst this error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions should always return a value (or throw an **@error**).
The version below will return null if not found – it won't render anything just show the warning.

```
$mq-breakpoints: (
    mobile:  320px,
    tablet:  740px,
    desktop: 980px,
    wide:    1300px
);

@function mq-get-breakpoint-width($name, $breakpoints: $mq-breakpoints) {
    $width: map-has-key($breakpoints, $name);
    @if not $width { @warn("Breakpoint #{$name} wasn't found in $breakpoints.") }
    @return $width;
}


test {
    width: mq-get-breakpoint-width(not-there); // will not be rendered
}
```